# using javascript to check if the ClassName in the paragraph equals the TextContent in the button

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to check if the class of the paragraph equals to the text in the button

```
<p id="test" class="test zero">This is the testing Paragraph</p>
    <button id="button" type="button">Test</button>
    <p id="result"></p>



var myP = document.getElementById("test"),
  myBtn = document.getElementById("button"),
  myResult = document.getElementById("result");

myBtn.onclick = function () {
  if (
    myP.classList.contains("test") ==
    myBtn.textContent.toLowerCase()
  ) {
    myResult.textContent =
      "Yes, the Paragraph contains the same ClassName as Button's Text Content";
  } else {
    myResult.textContent =
      "Nope, the Paragraph doesn't contain the same ClassName as Button's Text Content";
  }
};
```

as you see, I have put (==) but it's not working, can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried calling ```myBtn.textContent.trim()``` before comparing the strings? There might be whitespaces in the text, which could cause problems. [Reference to the .trim() Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myP.classList.contains("test")` returns a *boolean*, and `myBtn.textContent.toLowerCase()` returns a lowercased string. They won't be `==`.

Pass the text content into `.contains` instead:

```js
var myP = document.getElementById("test"),
  myBtn = document.getElementById("button"),
  myResult = document.getElementById("result");

myBtn.onclick = function() {
  if (
    myP.classList.contains(myBtn.textContent.toLowerCase())
  ) {
    myResult.textContent =
      "Yes, the Paragraph contains the same ClassName as Button's Text Content";
  } else {
    myResult.textContent =
      "Nope, the Paragraph doesn't contain the same ClassName as Button's Text Content";
  }
};
```

```html
<p id="test" class="test zero">This is the testing Paragraph</p>
<button id="button" type="button">test</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you. and i also tried `myP.classList.contains("test").toString` and it also didn't work so shouldn't this return a string as well?

Comment: `.contains(..).toString` will return the string `'true'` or the string `'false'` - but here, you're comparing it against `test`, which won't work.

Answer (score 1):

`myP.classList.contains("test")` returns either `true` or `false`. That won't be equal to the text of the button (unless the button's text is `true` or `false`, but that still won't tell you if the text matches the class).

You should get the text of the button, then check if the class list contains that:

```
if (myP.classList.contains(myBtn.textContent.toLowerCase()))
```